# How can I run code in functions.php when switch_theme() is called?

Tags: theme-development

I've got some code inside functions.php which is designed to execute only when the theme is first activated:

```
if ( is_admin() && isset($_GET['activated'] ) && $pagenow == 'themes.php' ) {
//this code only runs when the theme is first activated
}
```

However, I'm pretty sure this code is not running if the theme is activated outside the normal activation process. For example, if a switch_theme() statement is called from a plugin.

In that case, how might I alter my code above to execute on switch_theme()?

```
if ( is_admin() && isset($_GET['activated'] ) && $pagenow == 'themes.php') OR (switch_theme_called() ) ) {
//this code only runs when the theme is first activated
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, instead of using a $_GET parameter you could store a initiate state in your options-table.

E.g.

```
$initialized = get_option('mytheme_initialized');
if ( (false === $initialized) && is_admin() && ($pagenow == 'themes.php') ) {
//this code only runs when the theme is first activated
update_option('mytheme_initialized', true);
}
```

Unfortunately the "register_activation"-hook is only available for plugins -> http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13602

Comment: if the theme is being initialized from a plugin, won't $pagenow = 'themes.php' always be false?

Comment: You're right. You could just remove everything in the if statement and only check for the $initialized variable. This should do the trick. The first time the functions.php is called, the variable is set to true.

Comment: +1 Great so far. Could I use if(!$initialized && is_admin()) instead of if(false===$initialized) ?

Comment: With if(false === $var) you also test if the type of the variable is a boolean. If you use if($var) instead, the if-statement could also be true if a numeric 1 or string 'true' is submitted. But yes, the script will work with your adjustments.